# Uneven line spacing in two columns under a table

Tags: line-spacing

There are quite a few questions already answered on similar topics but I couldn't find an exact scenario such as mine. I have a table on a two-column page. The table is large so when it is placed on top of the page it leaves just enough space at the bottom of the page for six or seven lines of text. Now LaTeX places six lines of text in the left column (talking about the page column, not the table column) and seven in the right. The space taken by both the columns is the same, so the inter-line space in the left column is greater than in the right column which looks quite odd. I wonder if there's a way around it other than inserting (or deleting) something in (from) the text

Comment: How would such a solution work? There's an odd number of lines, so they can't be split evenly. What kind of solution are you looking for?

Comment: @ArunDebray you can make tex use an extra line, then it's even (see my answer)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Place

```
\looseness=1
```

before the paragraph of text TeX will attempt to set the paragraph using one extra line, so you should end up with 7 lines in each column.